# How to use Not contains function in string in UIPath?

Tags: uipath

I trying to find the syntax where I can use Not keyword with String.Contains condition in UIPath.

Example for :  I have following variable.

strValue = “This is Test”

I want to check whether 'Test' word is not existed in the variable then it should show me some message.

I have tried below approach but it did not work.

```
Not strValue.Contains(“Test”)
```

Comment: What language are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use indexOf(). It will return -1 if value to search is not present in string.

```
strValue = “This is Test”
var i = strValue.indexOf("Test");
if(i>0){
  console.log('Test is present in strValue');
}
```